# How to solve InaccesibleObjectException: module a does not "opens xyz.it" to unnamed module?

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, java-module, module-info

I am currenty trying to make use of the module path in my projects. I have a "module-info.java" file in my "src/main/java"-folder. But when it comes to running the integrationtests, it fails giving me the InaccessibleObjectException.
When i add the "opens xyz.it" line in the module-info-java file i get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ a ---
[INFO] Building jar: /path/to/a.jar'
jar: Package xyz.it missing from ModulePackages class file attribute
```

I hope someone can help solve this problem.

Comment: a command-line argument can help you with this `--add-opens=a/xyz.it=ALL-UNNAMED`

Comment: thx is it possible to make this more general ? We have a parent project where our surefire and failsafe plugins are configured. but our integrationtest package is always *.it . Or is it possible to overwrite just specific parts of the surefire and failsafe plugin configuration in child projects?

Comment: It's possible to override the configurations, but not much can be said about your specific case without looking at a reproducible example. Please edit the question accordiingly.